# How to double every frame (and the length of the video itself) in an mp4 video (timelapse)?

Tags: ffmpeg

The video has length of t and is 30fps. I want it to have a length of 2*t.
I just want each frame to be shown a little longer. According to VLC the codec is H264-MPEG4 AVC.
Is there some simple command with ffmpeg?

Comment: Any audio present?

Comment: No audio. I may add some later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setpts` filter can be used to retime frames. Basic usage is

```
ffmpeg -i in -vf setpts=PTS*2 out.mp4
```

`PTS*2` sets output timestamp of each frame to 2x its input value.